# A mental model to traverse Django files

Tags: django

There are multiple files in Django:

```
  urls.py views.py models.py templates and forms.py to create data.
```

The diagram of it enables you to understand the functions and principles.
take a popular vertical map for instance.

> [MTV diagram](http://wiki.openhatch.org/images/thumb/f/fd/Mtv-diagram.png/400px-Mtv-diagram.png)

It's frustrating if you traverse the fils vertically in mind when shift from file to file in editor.

What's is a good structure to picture and see them in brain.

Comment: I have no idea what are you asking. Perhaps you want something like this? https://qph.ec.quoracdn.net/main-qimg-23768cfe8a5c4be3c6b6d26611b8d651 (not really up-to-date with new things like Django Channels, but still valid for a "classic" mvc approach)

Comment: ask for a mental model to map django's files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to picture django files mentally?

You can try this:

```
browser -> urls -> view -> template
               |     ^
               |   model
               |
               `-> other view -> other template
                     ^
                   other model
```